# What happens to terminated tasks in a ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, purge, scheduledexecutorservice

I am currently modifying an application to use a ScheduledExecutorService in place of a Timer and I don't know what to do with my old `Timer.purge()`.

How are things handled with an Executor? Do I have to worry about anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent for the Executor. When tasks are cancelled their reference will be removed from the Executor.

However the lifecycle of the Executor is managed with `shutdown()` so you should call that when the Executor is no longer required.

Comment: I wanted to make sure of that since it is not mentioned anywhere. I already changed the `Timer.cancel()` to `Executor.shutdown()`.